# Vim search for pattern replaces search pattern

Tags: vim

I try to search my file `%s/` by pattern `Audi`, and what I would expect is that `Vim` should only search but not replace what I'm searching by empty space.

Here an example:

**my.file**:

```
BMW = 0
Audi = 1
Ford = 2
```

When I perform search like so: `:%s/Audi` Vim does search in **my.file** for string that first has `Audi` pattern in it. And what comes next surprised me: it does replace `Audi` with white space.

Like it is not a big deal when your string is just 4 letters long, but I have some configuration files on my VPS and some of the config vars has the length of 20-30 symbols.

**Question:** How could I achieve just-search-but-not-replace behavior in `Vim`?

Comment: `:s` is the substitute command. Use `/` if you just want to search.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **melpomene** has mentioned in comments section:

> `:s` is the substitute command. Use `/` if you just want to search.